# MySQL Trigger Error when trying to generate end_date from start_date + duration

Tags: mysql, triggers, mamp

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osUiz.png)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3N8L.png)

Hi

I am receiving this message when I try to use this trigger to calculate a end_date. The duration Integer is from another table. This is being done in MySQL on Mamp enviorment

Any help appreciated

**code used**
`DELIMITER //`

`CREATE TRIGGER m_duration_ins_tr1`

`BEFORE INSERT ON memberships`
`FOR EACH ROW`
`BEGIN`
`DECLARE duration INTEGER;`
`SELECT duration FROM membership_type WHERE`
`membership_type_id = NEW.member_type;`
`SET NEW.end_date := DATE_ADD(NEW.start_date, INTERVAL duration MONTH);`
`END //`
`DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I don't understand why this is a trigger at all!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to replace

`SELECT duration FROM membership_type WHERE
membership_type_id = NEW.member_type;`

with

`SET duration = SELECT duration FROM membership_type WHERE membership_type_id = NEW.member_type LIMIT 1;`

The bare SELECT was doing nothing to assign to your local variable, but was indeed basically an attempt to return a result set from your trigger as the error suggested.

Answer (score 0):

trigger event can be INSERT , UPDATE or DELETE . 
I dont think you can select .
Try mysql workbench to create trigger